# Is there a .NET Framework equivalent to .NET Core's IControllerActivator?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, f#

The book Dependency Injection: Principles and Practices describes how to set up dependency injection using an `IControllerActivator` implementation. In an ASP.NET Core project, this can be added to the program's services in the `Startup.ConfigureServices()` method. This all makes sense.

However, ASP.NET *Framework* (4.7.2) doesn't use the same model. There is no `Startup` class. There is an `IControllerActivator` interface, but it's in a different namespace (`System.Web.Mvc` vs `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers`), has different members, and when I try to call the following:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
    config.Services.Add(typeof(IControllerActivator), new CompositionRoot());
```

...I get the exception `The service type IControllerActivator is not supported.`

**The ultimate goal here is to be able to define parameter-using constructors on ApiControllers and have the controller be instantiated by resolving it from a DI container when the service receives a request.**

**How can I implement this pattern in .NET Framework?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming this is an ASP.NET MVC app, so you use a `DependencyResolver` to do it.

I don't know what IoC Container you are using, but all the major ones have builtin support for it through their nuget packages. For example, here is [AutoFac docs](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/mvc.html), and here is [StructureMap docs](https://structuremap.github.io/integrations/) for integrating with ASP.NET MVC.